# React Material UI Multiline Textfield OnSubmit won't fire

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to design a text input box similar to Slack's style.  Where you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to do a newline and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit.  Is this feasible with Material UIs textfield or even Material UI at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use text field of material-ui, by default it provides only one line in input field, but you can extend to multiline also by setting the bool `multiLine={true}`.

In case of multiline <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will work as you want. Something like this:

```
<TextField
    hintText="MultiLine with rows: 2 and rowsMax: 4"
    multiLine={true}
    rows={2}
    rowsMax={4}
/>
```

To put more customisation you can specify the rows and max rows also. Enter functionality you can achieve in the onchange event, by checking the key code of enter key like this:

```
onChange(event, value){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        //put the logic here
    }
```

check all the properties and specifications : 
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore as the enter keypress is not picked up by the TextField component's onChange handler